# cx_Freeze: cannot input ExcelFormulaParser

Tags: python, excel, cx-freeze, xlwt

So I am trying to compile my code into an .exe using cx_freeze.

Here is the code I am using to compile it...

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import numpy.core._methods
import numpy.lib.format
from xlwt import ExcelFormulaParser


additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']

setup(name='ReconApp',
      version='0.1',
      description='xyz.script',
      options = {'build_exe': {'includes': additional_mods}},
      executables = [Executable("reconciliation_application.py")])
```

The code compiles [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7cvs.png)with no errors.
When I go to run the .exe the program launches and closes with this error.

I notice that it does not like something inside xlwt module ExcelFormulaParser
By I do not know what the error is.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add xlwt library to setup options, i.e.

```
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["numpy", "matplotlib", "xlwt"]}

setup(
    name = "App",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "App ...",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("App.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```